# Increasing the mouse pointer size for a tutorial video

Tags: windows-10, video, mouse, cursor, mouse-cursor

I am running Windows 10.  I would like to make a video tutorial by recording my screen.  To do this well, I think my mouse pointer should be more noticeable than it is at its default size and color.  I have tried various solutions for this.  Aesthetically, the best appears to be to increase cursor size via Settings > Devices > Mouse > Adjust mouse & cursor size.  I have also changed the pointer color to blue in this location.

I then use a program to record my screen.  The output is generally an MP4 file, which I save locally.  Two examples of programs that can record my screen are Xbox Game Bar, which is built into Windows 10, and Free Cam, a free program I found online.  In both cases, the MP4 file produced shows the cursor pointer at the new color (blue) but not the larger size.

My question is, working from this basis, what is my best option to preserve the larger pointer size in videos like this?

Comment: Have you tried selecting another cursor, e.g. Windows Standard (extra large)? see https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-change-your-mouse-cursor-pointer/

Comment: @DrMoishe Yes, but the application requires a larger pointer size.  (The window where the video will be played is relatively small.)  My settings are pointer size 5 and the suggested blue on the "Adjust mouse & cursor size" panel.  I've also explored the Open Cursor Library and the free version of Stardock CursorFX, but the aesthetics of both are dated and not really suitable for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try Flashback Express, https://www.flashbackrecorder.com/express/

It's free, although it does nag you to buy Flashback Pro.  Flashback Pro includes video editing but if you have a different way of editing your videos then Flashback Express is all you need for recording.

The weird thing about Flashback Express is that you change the cursor size after you've recorded the video, not before.

Flashback Express is two applications: Flashback Express Recorder and Flashback Express Player.  Once you've recorded your video with Flashback Express Recorder it will open automatically in Flashback Express Player.  In Flashback Express Player, with the recorded video open, select Effects > Highlight Cursor...  You can change the cursor size as well as highlighting it with a yellow circle (yellow by default but you can change the colour and size of the circle).

Note you'll only be able to access the Effects menu in the Player if you have a recorded video loaded.  If there is no video loaded the Effects menu is disabled.

Flashback Express records videos in its own *.fbr format.  However, you can convert them to MPEG4, AVI or WMV formats via Flashback Express Player's File menu > Export...

Answer (score 0):

I use ScreenHunter 7 Pro.

It captures and records large cursors. No changes are required. It just gets what you have on screen.

It has a free version too.